# Confusion about vanishing of ideal sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There is this result [stacks project lemma 29.5.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/056J) which makes sense on a technical level but seems to leads to some conclusions that don't make sense to me.

Let $Z$ be a closed subscheme of a noetherian scheme $X$ with coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$. Since as a set $Z = \operatorname{Supp} \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$, we know that $\mathcal{I}_x = \mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ for $x \notin Z$. Similarly, if $z \in Z$, then $I_z \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X, z}$ is a proper ideal. As such, $\mathcal{I}_z \subseteq \mathfrak{m}_z$, since otherwise $\mathcal{I}_z$ would contain an invertible element. Hence, $\mathcal{I}|_z = \mathcal{I}_z \otimes k(z) = 0$. This would then imply that $\mathcal{I}_z = 0$ by the lemma, but I don't think this is generally the case for all $z \in Z$.

What is going wrong here?

Thank you very much!

My apologies for all the edits; I didn't want to leave the older form up since it was basically asking the same question again. I am more than happy to revert the question to its older form if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is concluding that $\mathcal{I}_z\otimes k(z)=0$ from $\mathcal{I}_z\subset \mathfrak{m}_z$. In fact, as $k(z)\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,z}/\mathfrak{m}_z$, we have $\mathcal{I}_z\otimes k(z)\cong \mathcal{I}_z/\mathfrak{m}_z\mathcal{I}_z$. For a concrete example, if $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ and $Z$ is cut out by $t$, then taking $z=(t)$ we get that $\mathcal{I}_z=(t)\subset k[t]_{(t)}$, which when tensored with $k(t)=k[t]/(t)$ becomes $(t)/(t^2)\cong k$. (You want to mod out by the elements of $I_z$ which can be written as something in the maximal ideal times something in $I_z$, not just things in $I_z$ which are also in the maximal ideal.)

Comment: Ah of course. I was thinking about the tensor product incorrectly. Thank you for your patience with all my edits!