# Computation of $\operatorname{Tor}^{\mathbb{Q}[x,y]}_1(\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x,y), (x, y))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and $I = (x,y)$. I am confused about this computation of $\operatorname{Tor}^{R}_1(R/I, I)$, since I am getting an incorrect answer from the definitions.

I considered the exact sequence of $R$-modules $$0 \to R \to R^{\oplus 2} \to I \to 0$$ where the first map is $h \mapsto (-hy, hx)$ and the second map is $(f,g) \mapsto fx + gy$. This is exact since, if $fx + gy = 0$ then $f \in (y)$, $g \in (x)$ so we may write $fx + gy = (f' + g')(xy) = 0$ for polynomials $f', g'$ satisfying $f = f'y, g = g'x$. To compute $\operatorname{Tor}^{R}_1(R/I, R)$ we note that the exact sequence above is a free resolution of $(x,y)$ so we just need to compute the homology of the complex $$0 \to R/I\to R/I^{\oplus 2} \to 0$$ where the map in the middle is the zero map, since $hx, hy \in (x,y)$. Then $\operatorname{Tor}_1$ should be the homology at $R/I$ and $\operatorname{Tor}_0$ the homology at $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x,y)^{\oplus 2}$. The maps are all zero maps so we conclude that $\operatorname{Tor}_1(R/I, I) = R/I \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and $\operatorname{Tor}_0(R/I, I) = R/I^{\oplus 2} \cong \mathbb{Q}^{\oplus 2}$.

Now, this cannot be, since $\operatorname{Tor}_0(R/I, I) \cong R/I \otimes_R I = 0$. Really, by the right exactness of $R/I \otimes -$ the map $R/I \to R/I^{\oplus 2}$ should be surjective too, which is absurd since it would be a surjective linear map $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}^{2}$.

What is the mistake in my computation above?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding right-exactness, the original map $R\to R^{\oplus 2}$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation is essentially correct, but your succeeding claims are what is incorrect. First, $R/I \otimes_R I \ne 0$. Indeed, for any $R$-module $M$, there is an isomorphism $R/I \otimes_R M \cong M/IM$, and here $I/I^2 \ne 0$. Indeed, in line with your computation, $I/I^2 \cong (R/I)^{\oplus 2}$.

Furthermore, as Michael noted in the comments, the map $R \to R^{\oplus 2}$ is not surjective (its cokernel is $I$), so there is no surjectivity for right exactness to preserve.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly enough, I made the same mistake [four months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415866/confusion-about-vanishing-of-ideal-sheaves). Someday I will learn how to tensor with quotients!